# Что значит это высказывание Л. Н. Толстого?

Tags: литературоведение

«Мы любим людей за то добро, которое мы им сделали, и не любим за то зло, которое мы им делали».

Объясните, что он имел в виду.

Comment: Как вариант такая трактовка:
«Мы любим людей за то добро, которое мы сделали благодаря им, и не любим за то зло, которое мы делали благодаря им».
Но лучше спросить у Толстого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем больше вкладываешься в человека, тем больше его ценишь. А перед тем, кому ты напакостил, тебе потом стыдно, и ты себя же убеждаешь, что лучше больше ничего общего с тем, кого обидел, не иметь, ибо так спокойнее жить. Другими словами, нам приятно общаться с теми, для кого мы хорошие, и неприятно общаться с теми, для кого мы плохие.

Comment: спасибо, а какие есть лит-е произведения, в которых  это проявляется?

Comment: @Lines В романе Дюма "20 лет спустя" мушкетёры приравнивали Мордаунта к чудовищу не в последнюю очередь из-за того, что сами же казнили его мать. Разглядеть в нём жертву, сироту и человека, требующего возмездия, им было не с руки. Поэтому он был злым уже в силу того, что когда-то они сделали ему зло сами. Это им удобная позиция.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что этими словами выражен взгляд на *склонность человека оправдывать свои действия* и воспринимать себя позитивно, как человека справедливого и последовательного. Если человек причинил кому-то зло, то его подсознание находит этому оправдание; "жертва" воспринимается как человек плохой, заслуживший такое обращение, а "плохого" не любят и стараются не вспоминать в случаях, когда в справедливости своих поступков сомневаются (такое сомнение бывает далеко не всегда и не у всех). Любят же тех, кому сделали добро, - по причине того, что подсознательно любят *себя* в делах своих и ценят ответную реакцию тех, кому помогли, воспринимая их как людей отзывчивых и доброжелательных (условно говоря, в них "вложились", посвятили им дела или помыслы).